# Split foreach based on even/odd

Tags: php, html, magento

I currently use a code to display some content in my Magento shop.
But now I want to split the loaded content based on even/odd into two different divs.

My current code is displayed below.

How can I split the code based on even/odd so that I get to `<div class="block-specs">`.

I want two div's `<div class="block-specs odd">` and `<div class="block-specs even">`

But inside that div only the content of the even or odd should be displayed.

So that I get two main divs, two display left/right.

How can I achieve that, so that I split the foreach code?

EDIT CODE:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $a => $_additional){ $additionalgroup_oddeven[(++$i % 2)][$a] = $_additional; }; ?>
<?php foreach($additionalgroup_oddeven[0] as $_additional){ ?>
<div class="block-specs-<?php echo $i?>">
    <h3 class="specs-<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
    <table class="data-table specs-<?php echo $i?>" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
         <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Current code:

```
<?php if($_additionalgroup = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<section id="additional">
<div class="box-collateral box-additional">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++; $oddEven =($i % 2) ? 'odd':'even';?>
    <div class="block-specs-<?php echo $i?>">
        <h3 class="specs-<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
        <table class="data-table specs-<?php echo $i?>" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
             <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
</section>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Split the array into two by looping thru all items and then, construct your divs based on those 2 arrays.

Comment: @lshettyl Thanks! Can you give me a example of what you mean?

Comment: @HenkZ   Even with the Edited Code, the issue is still that **you are echoing $i as the suffix for the <div's classname**. Unfortunately; **$i is an Integer... not a String** You can simply **substitute $i for $oddEven**. You can ***see another variant of this in my post*** too... Cheers.  ;-)

Comment: I updated my previous code... you may want to take a look at it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I came up with.
Could you try it and give us some Feedback:

```
<?php if($_additionalgroup = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
            <section id="additional">
                <div class="box-collateral box-additional">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

                    <?php $oddDataContent = ""; $evenDataContent = ""; ?>
                    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++; $oddEven =($i % 2) ? 'odd':'even';?>
                        <?php ob_start(); ?>
                        <div class="block-specs-<?php echo $i?>">
                            <h3 class="specs-<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
                            <table class="data-table specs-<?php echo $i?>" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
                                <col width="25%" />
                                <col />
                                <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
                                    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
                                    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                                            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
                        <?php $contentData = ob_get_clean(); if($oddEven == 'even'){$evenDataContent .= $contentData; }else{$oddDataContent .= $contentData;} ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <!-- HERE'S TO THE TRICK:-->            
                    <!-- MANUALLY CREATE THE DIV ODD & EVEN DIVS HERE -->
                    <div class="blocs-specs-odd">
                        <!-- INSERT YOUR ODD CONTENT DATA HERE:-->
                        <?php echo $oddDataContent;?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="blocs-specs-even">
                        <!-- INSERT YOUR EVEN CONTENT DATA HERE:-->
                        <?php echo $evenDataContent;?>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </section>
        <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks! But in that case I still get a lot of div's, with only new classes. I just want to create two upper divs, left and right. So that inside that div only the even or odd values are displayed.

Comment: @HenkZ  Ahha... now i get it... ok... my bad :-( I'd try looking into it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, hopefully you know a solution to this problem! :)

Comment: @HenkZ         I already updated the previous code... you just have to test it out yourself... i commented it a bit so that you might get my drift... let me know, then, how it goes....

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks a lot. Works perfect

Comment: Cool.... You are the inspiration not me... in essence you solved it by believing i could ;-)  That's the power of Trusting without knowing the result. So in Truth: Faith could be also practical and scientific too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($example as $exp){
?>
<div class="<?=$($i % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd'?>"></div>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Try and actually explain what you are doing and why, don't just drop a ton of code here

Answer (score 0):

this way you can split the results into a multi dimensional array

`foreach ($_additionalgroup as $a => $_additional){ $additionalgroup_oddeven[(++$i % 2)][$a] = $_additional; }`

then you can `foreach` over the specific group like

`foreach($additionalgroup_oddeven[0] as $_additional){ /* first div */ }` 
`foreach($additionalgroup_oddeven[1] as $_additional){ /* second div */ }`

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following code before echoing any HTML, to split the `$_additionalgroup` array into two arrays containing the odds and the evens.
Note that `isOdd` is not a `PHP` function, you need to implement it yourself, I just added it for the sake of simplicity.

```
$oddArr = array();
$evenArr = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($_additionalgroup); $i++)
{
     $value = $_additionalGroup[$i];
     if(isOdd($i)
     {
         $oddArr[] = $value;
     }
     else
     {
         $evenArr[] = $value;
     }
 }
```